# Switch or if/elseif/else inside golang HTML templates

Tags: html, templates, go, go-templates

I have this struct :

```
const (
    paragraph_hypothesis = 1<<iota
    paragraph_attachment = 1<<iota
    paragraph_menu       = 1<<iota
)

type Paragraph struct {
    Type int // paragraph_hypothesis or paragraph_attachment or paragraph_menu
}
```

I want to display my paragraphs in a `Type` dependent way.

The only solution I found was based on dedicated functions like `isAttachment` testing the `Type` in Go and nested `{{if}}` :

```
{{range .Paragraphs}}
    {{if .IsAttachment}}
        -- attachement presentation code  --
    {{else}}{{if .IsMenu}}
        -- menu --
    {{else}}
        -- default code --
    {{end}}{{end}}
{{end}}
```

In fact I have more types, which makes it even weirder, cluttering both the Go code with `IsSomething` functions and the template with those `{{end}}`.

What's the clean solution ? Is there some `switch` or `if/elseif/else` solution in go templates ? Or a completely different way to handle these cases ?

Comment: Are you referring to html templates? Your example of the `Paragraph` type is not too clear. You can generally create custom template behaviour by adding functions to the FuncMap (http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs). Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Templates are logic-less. They're not supposed to have this kind of logic. The maximum logic you can have is a bunch of `if`.

In such a case, you're supposed to do it like this:

```
{{if .IsAttachment}}
    -- attachment presentation code --
{{end}}

{{if .IsMenu}}
    -- menu --
{{end}}

{{if .IsDefault}}
    -- default code --
{{end}}
```

Comment: And is there no other way to test the `Type` than to add `isSomeValue` functions ?

Comment: @dystroy well, the point is to move the logic out of the template. So yes, you're supposed to have a helper function out of it. It's the same kind of thing you have to do in other technologies whenever you use logicless templates.

Comment: In fact, the problem starts with the definition of `IsDefault`. In the end you start by duplicating all presentation logic which must be present both in the templates and in the Go code and you end with a big verbose code in Go to support the template and the template brings no added value.

Comment: This is too rigid no?... what is a condition need to evaluate against a string? @FlorianMargaine

Comment: replace: "text/template is not supposed to have this kind of logic."
with: "text/template does not support more sophisticated logic."

Comment: There is `else` and `else if`

Comment: [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions) package provides helper functions for sophisticated logic. When  `{{else if .IsMenu}}` would not suffice, you could do something like `{{if and .IsMenu (not .IsAttachment)}}`.

Comment: What does "Templates are logic-less" even mean. Of course you can add logic in the template.

Comment: Hey there, so no `{{else}}` like logic is provided? Because `{{if .MyStruct.Name.IsNil}}foo{{end}}{{if .MyStruct.Name.IsNotNil}}bar{{end}}` is quite redundant..

Answer (score 66):

Yes, you can use `{{else if .IsMenu}}`

Comment: This works. Maybe this is a new feature for templates. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve `switch` functionality by adding custom functions to the [template.FuncMap](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#FuncMap).

In the example below I've defined a function, `printPara (paratype int) string` which takes one of your defined paragraph types and changes it's output accordingly.

Please note that, in the actual template, the `.Paratype` is piped into the `printpara` function. This is how to pass parameters in templates. Please note that there are restrictions on the number and form of the output parameters for functions added to `FuncMap`s. [This page](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) has some good info, as well as the first link.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {

    const (
        paragraph_hypothesis = 1 << iota
        paragraph_attachment = 1 << iota
        paragraph_menu       = 1 << iota
    )

    const text = "{{.Paratype | printpara}}\n" // A simple test template

    type Paragraph struct {
        Paratype int
    }

    var paralist = []*Paragraph{
        &Paragraph{paragraph_hypothesis},
        &Paragraph{paragraph_attachment},
        &Paragraph{paragraph_menu},
    }

    t := template.New("testparagraphs")

    printPara := func(paratype int) string {
        text := ""
        switch paratype {
        case paragraph_hypothesis:
            text = "This is a hypothesis\n"
        case paragraph_attachment:
            text = "This is an attachment\n"
        case paragraph_menu:
            text = "Menu\n1:\n2:\n3:\n\nPick any option:\n"
        }
        return text
    }

    template.Must(t.Funcs(template.FuncMap{"printpara": printPara}).Parse(text))

    for _, p := range paralist {
        err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, p)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("executing template:", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

> This is a hypothesis
>
> This is an attachment
>
> Menu
> 1:
> 2:
> 3:
>
> Pick any option:

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/WzjYnO9fRJ)

Hope that helps, I'm pretty sure the code could be cleaned up a bit, but I've tried to stay close to the example code you provided.

Comment: This is interesting but in your solution the rendering of the paragraph in HTML is made in Go (in `printPara`). Then there doesn't seem to be any point in using a template.

Comment: The printing is only as a demonstration. You can feasibly insert any code in the `case` statements, not just custom output. You could process variables, change struct values etc. This is really just to demonstrate how you could generate `switch` like functionality in templates.

Comment: @Intermernet but you're not generating any `switch` like functionality in templates there. I'd like to have a better example too I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ has all of the abilities and features of go native templates. Other than the inbuilt features listed there, adding functions to the FuncMap is the only way I  know to modify the output. @FlorianMargaine , The function accepts a single integer (the template could be something like `{{4 | printpara}}` for a menu) and, internally, changes it's behaviour by doing a switch statement on that integer. That's about as close to the native golang `switch` as I could emulate in a template.

Comment: @Intermernet I think both dystroy and I were looking for something like this: http://pastebin.com/QSz0vAxk

Comment: That's exactly the kind of things I was looking for.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine and @dystroy , Would the data driving the template be coming from structs? Possibly something like `type Paragraph struct{Paratype int, Text string}`?

Comment: @Intermernet yes, I had removed the other fields of the struct to make it simpler (and in my obviously wrong opinion of that time, to make it clearer).

Comment: @dystroy , ok, I think I can refactor the function to do close to what you want. It's an interesting challenge, I've even been reading the source code to try to determine how the `if` statements work in templates. `if` isn't one of the built in template functions, despite `not`, `and` and `or` being so. Hopefully I'll have something soon :-)

Comment: Ok, after much reading, it seems that I'd need to modify the standard library (in particular http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/parse/#NodeType , just for starters) to acheive a true switch statement. The next best thing would be a series of `{{if switch .Type | case 1}}...{{end}}` (defining custom `Switch()` and `Case()` functions in the FuncMap), at which point you may as well just go with standard if statements. Ah well, I've learnt a lot about lexers and parsers in the last hour or so! The relevant source, if you're interested, is at http://golang.org/src/pkg/text/template/parse/ .